# Android databinding: onClick -> startActivity

Tags: android, activity, android-intent, viewmodel, android-data-binding

Есть кнопка внутри фрагмента.
После нажатия на кнопку мы должны создать интент и запустить новую активность.
Вопрос: как это правильнее сделать с точки зрения архитектуры?

До databinding это было сделано прямо внутри фрагмента - на кнопку навешивался onClickListener, внутри которого всё и происходило.
А как это лучше сделать с databinding?
Есть вариант передать в разметку фрагмента activity и viewModel, затем в onClick кнопки сделать

```
android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.openActivity(activity)}"
```

но стартовать интенты из viewModel - это плохая практика.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы ничего не передавал в разметку. Я обрабатываю нажатие как раньше (в листинге фрагмента или активити)
`binding.viewButton.setOnClickListener {  }`. Насколько я понимаю viewModel не должна заниматься открытием activity. Можно сделать красиво с помощью аннотации `@BindingAdapter`

вот например как я открываю ссылку с помощью WebViewActiity

```kotlin
@BindingAdapter("openLink")
fun openLink(view: View, link: WebViewActivity.Link) {
    view.setOnClickListener {
        view.context.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(link.url)))
    }
}
```

Как это выглядит в разметке:

```kotlin
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textAds"
            style="@style/Text.Link"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/label_ads"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:openLink="@{Link.ADS}" />
```

Такой подход оправдан, теперь я могу быстро повторить поведение по нажатию на текст-ссылку, всего одной строкой `app:openLink="@{`ссылка`}"`.

Databinding призван ускорить разработку, очень удобно стало работать со списками передавая сущность в разметку элемента.

```
    <data>
        <variable
            name=""
            type="" />
    </data>
```

Comment: Влад, спасибо за подробный ответ! 
Я думал, что одно из преимуществ databinding - сокращение объема кода во фрагментах/активности. Например, вынести все BindingAdapter-методы в отдельный класс. 
Но, получается, в этом случае так не сделать? 
Выносить часть таких методов  в отдельный класс, а часть оставлять в фрагменте - совсем плохо. Получается, всё надо оставить внутри фрагмента и объем кода не сокращается.

Comment: @idmitrij2008 хотя на https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture говориться ровно о том, что вы пишете. Странно, но мне это не по вкусу. В любом случаи я нахожу строку _UI controllers such as activities and fragments are primarily intended to display UI data, react to user actions_. Так же существует правило, которое гласит _ViewModel should not contain Context or reference to classes that contain Context._ Придерживаясь этого, я просто обработаю нажатие в листинге фрагмента/активити и там же открою экран.

Comment: @idmitrij2008 можно конечно с помощью dataBinding открыть экран с верстки, но мне это кажется неким скрытием функционала, позже сложно будет найти это действие, при этом вы ничего не ускорили. Так же на этапе компиляции иногда сложно найти место ошибки при использовании dataBinding, часто не правильно указан тип или nullable свойство